# Upgrade H2 database programatically in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I'm using an `h2` database in spring boot. I'm still using an old version of `spring boot (2.2.2)` and therefore an old version of `h2 database (1.4.200)`. I would like to upgrade but this breaks with:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Unsupported database file version or invalid file header in file
```

is there a way already to make this upgrade smooth? I found this guide:

https://www.h2database.com/html/migration-to-v2.html

But I would like to make the upgrade transparent for the person deploying the application, i.e. the upgrade should be done without that the person notices and needs to carry out manual steps. One option that I was imagining would be detect before startup the current version. If it is an old one, dump the database, and reingest in one with a new version.

Do you see any alternative?

Can someone point to existing implementations of this?